# Tap in & out in UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

In UITapGestureRecognizer, when user tap in & then out do we get two different events for this?

I have put UITapUITapGestureRecognizer on one of my view & then when user tap in I need to change the color of the view & when user tap out (i.e. remove his finger from the point) the color should be changed back to original color. I am able to change the color on tap in but not on tap out.

Any advise?

Comment: For simple taps you may use touchesBegan & etc methods.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't (can't?) use gesture recognizers for that, since they are built to handle raw touch events and parse them into gestures. The "tap in" event isn't a gesture by itself though.

Use these :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: But I have data to manipulate in my view controller. With tap in & out I need to change the view as well as change the data on the screen.

Comment: So use the two methods I named :-) They behave pretty much the same, except that you get a lot more control over the events you're handling.

Comment: Now... touchesDidEnded is not getting called at all... :-(

Comment: Correction ::- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)iTouches withEvent:(UIEvent *)iEvent